# Array conditional must be same shape as self

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, conditional-statements, jupyter

I get this error when I attempt to compare to variable names such as:

```
compare = Search1.where(Search1UK>Search1DE)
compare
compare.fillna(0)
```

'Search1UK' and 'Search1DE' are both variable names in which I have assigned a name to identify columns within different data frames.

Anyone could help on this please?

Comment: Is this pandas? If so, you should add a tag for it.

Comment: Yes I am using Pandas, added the tag thanks

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
compare = Search1.where(Search1['Search1UK']>Search1['Search1DE'])
```